# How to refresh value or display the next value of a textbox when button click(saved)

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a form that will display the next value of the voucher_id in a textbox. I am able to do that. The problem is when I click the save button, the value of the textbox is the same. I have to close the form and re-run it to refresh the value of the textbox. Can anyone help me to display the next value after clicking the save button? Here's my code snipet

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim rcset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim conConnection As New ADODB.Connection
conConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
  App.Path & "\" & "db_finance.mdb;Mode=Read|Write"
conConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
conConnection.Open

Set rcset = conConnection.Execute("SELECT Max(voucher_id) FROM voucher")
Text1.Text = rcset(0) + 1

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Form_Load occurs only when you load your form, why don't you move this code in you own sub and call it in Form_Load and after the save in your click event?

Comment: Can you please educate me on how can i do that sir? I tried putting the above in a click button but still nothing happens.

Comment: You have your answer below, but keep in mind that using that approach to get the MAX value of a column doesn't work well for a multiuser solution. It is a lot better to have an Autoincrement column

Comment: @Lhie a small suggestion for your you could use `SELECT Max(voucher_id)+1 FROM voucher` instead of `SELECT Max(voucher_id) FROM voucher` and assign the value like `Text1.Text = rcset(0)`

Comment: @hector i tried your suggestion bu unfortunately it still doesn't work..

Comment: @Steve in my database, my column for the voucher_id is autoincrement. i just want to display the next value of the column in the textboox

Comment: If the column is already Autoincrement then your code is wrong. Try to add manually a new record using Access then delete it. Look at the value returned by MAX after you insert a new record and look at the real value stored by Access in your Autoincrement column

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
Private Sub NextID()
  Dim rcset As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim conConnection As New ADODB.Connection
  conConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
  Data Source=" & _
  App.Path & "\" & "db_finance.mdb;Mode=Read|Write"
  conConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  conConnection.Open
  Set rcset = conConnection.Execute("SELECT Max(voucher_id) FROM voucher")
  Text1.Text = rcset(0) + 1
End Sub

 Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
 Handles Me.Load
     Call NextID()
 End Sub

 Private Sub Button_Click(Val sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
 Handles Button1.Click
     '// CAll Save Function - your function to to save 
     Call NextID()
 End Sub
```

Comment: sir satson there is an error in the form_load 
'ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
 Handles Me.Load)'

Comment: Remove `)` in end or me.Load

Comment: Here's the error.. Compile error: User-defined type not defined

Comment: Menstion that line @Lhie